# C# - Mock Unit Test From Service Client

Tags: c#

Hi I have a test method is trying to Mock Unit Testing from Local ServiceClient using Visual Studio

```
[TestMethod()]
public void IsSuccess_ThanAllocateFund()
{
    string FundCode ="CodeABC123";   
    bool isAvailable = CheckFundAvialable(FundCode);
    bool result = db.AddFund("UserHaskins",FundCode);
    Assert.AreEqual(isAvailable, result);
}
```

First of all it is checking the fund. If fund available then it will add fund to user using following method

```
public bool CheckFundAvialable(FundCode)
{
    bool isAvailable =true;
    FundAvailableServiceClient _PartAvailabilityService = new FundAvailableServiceClient()
    int _Available = _FundAvailableService.GetAvailability(FundCode);
    if (_Available <= 0) {
     isAvailable = false;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

My ServiceClint  method are given bellow

```
public partial class FundAvailibilityServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyProject.IFundAvailibilityService>,
MyProject.IFundAvailibilityService
{
    public int GetAvailability(string stockCode)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetFundAvailibility(FundCode);
    }
```

}

And Add To Database; however I am trying to mock

```
public bool AddFund(string UserName, string FundCode)
{ 
  // Database add / Insert
  return true;  
}
```

Now my problem is that how I will do Mock for my ClientService in unit test;

Comment: which framwwork are you using for unittesting ?

Comment: Do you want test db by comparing value returned from service layer? I suppose service layer is on top of db layer.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx

Comment: Which mocking-framwork are you using? I suppose this question is by far too broad as you don´t provide any technology you´re going to work with, so it´ll soon be closed. Apart from this most mocking-frameweorks suppose that you´re members to be mocked are `virtual` in order to override them with an (anonmoyus) implementation.

Comment: I am trying not to use any framework; just trying to implement simple unit testing in visual studio;

Comment: But you said you want to Mock a method.  For this you will need to use a Mocking framework.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using VS I have found a similar issue with unit tests where some objects are really hard to replicate in a unit test scenario.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter
I've tried using this tool which is available to use when you're debugging, it will take any object that you'll see in your "autos" tab and you can send it to a c# or xml object that can be included in a unit test.

Comment: Hi @TLCONE What tool you used to solve your problem.

Comment: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter)

Comment: Unfortunately; it is not working for me; I will have to stick with Visual Studio Unit Testing